# Azure Application Gateway modifications take a considerable amount time to update

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Previously I built an application gateway using Terraform in Azure using HTTP only, this worked absolutely fine and I was able to update the application gateway further down the pipeline with cert-manager configuration (backend pool, backend settings, listeners, rules and probes). This further modification is done via Azure CLI in Powershell. This change should take no longer then 5 minutes.
[image: Update time prior to the SSL cert being added]

However, I've recently added a SSL PEM certificate to the application gateway to allow me to use HTTPS. Ever since this has been configured, any further tasks such as the cert-manager configuration (this is not relating to cert-manager, I'm using this as an example, I have various other scripts to further modify the application gateway), takes a long time to configure. 5 minutes has now turned into 50 minutes!
[image: Update time post SSL cert being added to AGW]
I'm running this code from Azure DevOps, but even if I make a manual change to the application gateway via the Azure portal, I'm still waiting a long time for any changes to take place. This has caused massive frustration, as I build/destroy non-prod environments daily, so I need to reduce this time back to how it was when I was just using HTTP without any SSL certs. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause for this... I had various DNS entries setup for the same Keyvault (due to HUB and Spoke), I removed the DNS entries for all the spokes and left just the HUB entry in. Once this entry was removed, the scripts returned to normal.